# VS 2017 - Solution Migration mishap with .Net Core

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, .net-core, visual-studio-2017

When migrating my solution from VS 2015 to VS 2017, my .Net Core library is also being migrated from .Net Core to .Net 4.6. How can I keep the lib pointing to .Net Core?

Comment: you should edit your question and include the content from project.json of the library to show what frameworks it is targeting before migration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VS 2017 does that if your project, even if it has been created pointing to Core, only points to the regular framework when you’re converting...